# phpMyAdmin - big int values always end with zero

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When inserting values like 1591823907560714, it always end up up with zeros

(1591866907560700) in my database and I don't know why. I am using bigint as

datatype and here is my sql statement:

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

```
// cast the object to an array
$user = (array)$user;

$userId = $user['id'];

$firstname = $user['firstName'];
$lastname = $user['lastName'];
$email = $user['email'];
$photoUrl = $user['photoUrl'];

$createUser = "INSERT INTO users (userId, firstname, lastname, email, photoUrl, phoneNumber) 
                       VALUES ('".$userId."','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$photoUrl',NULL)";
```

Should I parse or format the number before insert ?

[image]

Comment: Don't munge query strings user inputs.  Learn to use parameters.

Comment: Are you sure about the `$userId` value before to insert it?

Comment: Why don't you create an SQLFiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: I am 100% sure of the user id as I echo it before inserting it in my db

Comment: I am using json_decode ,should I parse the number before inserting it in my db ?

Comment: $user = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 // cast the object to an array
 $user = (array)$user;
 $userId = $user['id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, this problem was due to json_decode(), JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING should be passed as parameter

> **options** 
> Bitmask of JSON decode options. Currently there are two
>   supported options. The first is JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING that allows
>   casting big integers to string instead of floats which is the default.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> Example #5 json_decode() of large integers

```
<?php
$json = '{"number": 12345678901234567890}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));

?>
The above example will output:

object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["number"]=>
  float(1.2345678901235E+19)
}
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["number"]=>
  string(20) "12345678901234567890"
}
```

Now the value is correctly inserted as 1591866907560714